# Issue with setting default org in VSCode

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, sfdx-plugin

I am trying to set a default org in VScode but it is not working.
I get a Cannot read property 'getInstance' of undefined error.

ERROR running force:auth:web:login:  Cannot read property 'getInstance' of undefined

Command : sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias test --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername

Output : ERROR running force:auth:web:login:  Cannot read property 'getInstance' of undefined

Can anyone please help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this kind of issues are due to sfdx updates by salesforce, first step would be to [updating SFDX](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_update_cli.htm#sfdx_setup_update_cli) with `sfdx update` command.

If that doesn't work, try to [uninstall the salesforcedx Plug-In](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_uninstall.htm) with below command and [install it again](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm#sfdx_setup_install_cli).

```
sfdx plugins:uninstall salesforcedx
```

---

Edit: There is an [issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/564) on Salesforce CLI github project which mentions this.

Comment: This is basically a link-only answer, which may get this answer flagged for deletion. You should at least include the critical details in the answer.

Comment: I was being lazy and have updated the answer, thanks for the heads-up @sfdcfox

Comment: @Raul Thanks, SFDX update didnt work but uninstall and reinstalling did the trick